# Adding wav file data to excel

Tags: python, excel

I'm struggling over how to add data from multiple audio files into a column in Excel. I'm grabbing the data first from the audio files in a folder using a loop and then trying to add the information to the spreadsheet using another loop. I don't understand how to loop through the length of audio files in a folder while also looping through the data of said audio files and having both loops work together. I want to be able to iterate through the frames ONLY for the number of audio files in a given folder.

Here's the code:

```
import openpyxl, os, wave

os.chdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = wb['Sheet']

for audio_file in os.listdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles'):
    w = wave.open(audio_file)
    frames = w.getnframes()
    print(frames)
    for i in range(2, len(os.listdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles')) + 2):
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = frames

wb.save('audiofilesexcel.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used:

```
import openpyxl, os, wave

os.chdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = wb['Sheet']

r = 3

for audio_file in os.listdir('c:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\audiofiles'):
    w = wave.open(audio_file)
    frames = w.getnframes()
    sheet.cell(row = r, column = 4).value = frames
    r += 1

wb.save('audiofilesexcel.xlsx')
```